# MSSQL c++ connector

Tags: c++, sql-server

I am looking for a way to connect to a MS SQL database from a unmanaged C++ program.
The only thing that I found is http://www.sqlapi.com/, but this is payed, any idea of a free alternative?

Also I would like a solution that has both a Linux and Windows connector.

Comment: (On the Windows side of things, looks like ADO [NB: not the same as ADO.NET] might be worth looking at - but I'm afraid I know very little about this(!))

Comment: There are native ODBC and ADO drivers for MS SQL on Windows.

Comment: thank you marnir and Alan for your suggestions. I was hoping there is a Linux/Windows solution.

Comment: ODBC is a platform-independent standard and appears to be [available on Linux](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/linux.html).

Comment: unfortunately the platform independent drivers in the link are not free.

Answer (score 0):

How about standart API: ODBC?

You may see a good example of connector in this link:

http://cs.dvc.edu/HowTo_SQL.html

But there are a string:

```
char db[] = "myDatabase"; // ODBC database name
```

It isn't a database name, it's name of server. For example: MSSQLSERVER.